# What is the WPF equivalent to ControlPaint.Light?

Tags: wpf, winforms, colors

What is the wpf equivalent to ControlPaint.Light?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wz9t9fy%28VS.80%29.aspx

Given that WinForms uses System.Drawing.Color and wpf uses System.Windows.Media.Color

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They both have ARGB values, you so can easily create one from the other at run time.

Comment: It is a pity they didn't include a casting operator for this.