# Retrieve the Default Selection Opacity

Tags: wpf, systemcolors

Text selection in WPF (text boxes etc.) looks different from that of other UI toolkits, as WPF uses a semi-transparent overlay over the text for its selection rectangle.

The [`SystemColors` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides the color used for that rectangle in the [`HighlightColor` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.highlightcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and the other properties related to it). However, that color is fully opaque. Hence, the color has to be used as a reduced opacity.

Documentation pages on [`TextBoxBase.SelectionOpacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectionopacity%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [`PasswordBox.SelectionOpacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.selectionopacity%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and on [`FlowDocumentPageViewer.SelectionOpacity`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176841/what-is-the-wpf-equivalent-to-controlpaint-light) suggest:

> The default is 0.4.

On the other hand, [this blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/28/selection-brush.aspx) says:

> *SelectionOpacity* (...) defaults to a value of .6.

Whatever that default value is, **is there any way to retrieve the selection opacity to be used with `SystemColors.HighlightColor` from the environment, rather than hardcoding an arbitrary value** (which may not even be the best choice for non-standard highlight colors)?

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and yes.. There is no `SystemColors.HighlightOpacity` - but there should be.

The `SelectionOpacity` default property value  is **hardcoded** to 0.4 in WPF: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/TextBoxBase.cs,9716201433499854

I don't exactly know how this can differ(0.6 as you said), it seems to be hardcoded as 0.4 in every .NET that supports it(4.0, 4.5).

If you want to actually query the default value of `SelectionOpacityProperty`, you can do so:

```
var prop = TextBoxBase.SelectionOpacityProperty;
var defValue = (double) prop.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue; // 0.4
```

Comment: Well, it can differ if a future .NET version (or even another WPF implementation) uses a different value. It just feels like a bug waiting to cause trouble to just assume the value will always be 0.4 in my application. (I consider accepting this answer, though I usually let some time pass first in case someone else has any further information. +1 for now.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper; in the sense, yes, it's hardcoded, but nothing stops you from querying the default value of `SelectionOpacityProperty`, not sure I understand what' the problem exactly is. You should not hardcode 0.4 in your own code.

Comment: That is actually a good idea to ensure the value I am using is always the same as what is used by for text boxes by default. I will use this solution, hoping that the selection opacity will not, at some point in the future, be made actually configurable.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Theoretically, they can already override the `SelectionOpacity` property at runtime through themes(Aero, Aero2, AeroLite, Classic, Royal, Luna, ..), the `DefaultValue` wouldn't reflect this, however, that would be bad move from their part, as right now they have `SYstemColors.` key for anything that changes throughout the themes, but they don't have one for `SelectionOpacity`.